# After call accept() in a network server run by systemd. Netstat doesn't show my service

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, systemd

I am not sure if anyone has asked this before. 
There is a service running fine on my Linux server (3.14.39) by systemd.
Now, I want to add a function which creates a thread and bring up a small network server listening to port `6666`.
Simply do,

```
   memset(&server_addr,0, sizeof(server_addr)); 
   server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
   server_addr.sin_port = htons(6666);

   server_socket = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
   setsockopt(server_socket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&opt,sizeof(opt));
   bind(server_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&server_addr,sizeof(server_addr));
   listen(server_socket, 10);
   new_server_socket = accept(server_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&length);
```

All of above calls return successfully and the program seems waiting the client connection.

However, when I use `netstat -a` to check my server state there is nothing!
And I cannot connect to the socket by telnet either.

```
 netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::6556                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I did an experiment to extract the same C subroutine and build it as an standalone executable server program then run it after system boot up. Everything works fine.... So I suppose it is not coding error, firewall.

I also check the `lsof -ni`  and I can see my server and socket information.

```
root@:lsof -ni |grep 25199
316  /usr/sbin/test   socket:[25199]
```

Hope I am clear myself..
I just have no clue and direction how to debug this. Anyone has idea what I can do or check right now? Even suggest a document would help! 
Thanks!

---

Add more information

```
1. ping 127.0.0.1 is ok so I guess LO is up

    root@:~# ping 127.0.0.1
    PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
    64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
    64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
    64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
    64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
```

2. I suspect that my service may be brought up before the network so I add network-online.target in my systemd unit file. But it's not working either.

   After=network-online.target

Comment: "*... program seems waiting the client connection.*" how do you validate this?

Comment: Where is the code that initializes the bind-address?

Comment: Hi alk, thank you for the reply. I added logs before and after bind() while I was debugging this issue. I can see the log before bind() is printed but the log after didn't.

Comment: Hi EJP, thanks. The bind-address init code are 
    memset(&server_addr,0 , sizeof(server_addr)); 
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(6666);

Comment: Sorry guys. Still I am new with the stackoverflow. Just add my init code in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pasting code in the comment doesn't work well. My bind-address init code is as below..

```
   memset(&server_addr,0, sizeof(server_addr)); 
   server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
   server_addr.sin_port = htons(6666);
```

Comment: You should have pasted it into your question, where it should have been in the first place.

Comment: Added in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved,
It turns out the network namespace issue.

Somehow the systemd service I got join another network namespace called "xxns".
While netstat only list the default ns status, I cannot see the port 6666.
Using following command and I can see the port status.

```
ip netns exec xxns netstat -ant
```

Telnet also works with

```
ip netns exec xxns telnet 127.0.0.1 6666
```

Because I have never used linux namespace before, so my debugging direction is totally incorrect and my information provided above are useless...